# How to run a headless Monaco Editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to communicate with an ITextModel without using an editor.
My environment can't performantly render HTML so I'd like to render natively and communicate over javascript with a model, forwarding/receiving events like render, scroll, type, selection, completion etc.

Realizing this is not the intended use, I'd still like to tap in to the API with as little as possible private API use.

First hurdle is understanding the scrolling/visible text region/font rendering cycle.
Can anyone point me at the right direction for where this is set up in relation to the model?

Comment: please add more detail to your question.  Specificy your environment, what exactly do you mean by 'headless'?  More detail means we can give you answers faster.